# flyway-sbt plugin repo seems to be unavailable, does it have any backup mirror?

Tags: sbt, flyway

Using `http://flywaydb.org/repo` resolver leads to unresolved plugin dependency and we could not make artifactory support sbt plugin naming convention. Is there any mirror for the plugin?

Comment: What error are you seeing? What version of SBT do you use? Could you reproduce by following the steps of the getting started tutorial *exactly*? Here is the manual download url as a fallback: http://flywaydb.org/getstarted/download.html

Comment: Hi Axel. It seems like your repo was down for a couple of hours and our build was in :-( condition. We were unable to put flyway-sbt jar to the Artifactory because of SBT plugin artifacts naming convention (artifact name, that contains the SBT & Scala versions with a jar name that doesn't have them). I guess we should try to update the artifactory, because it is quite outdated. Maybe you know any other workaround to this issue, so the builds won't depend on a single repo?